# What breaks this code?

Tags: c++, qt, compilation, compiler-errors, syntax-error

I am sorry to ask a question with such a "meaningful" title, but I just can't get what the compiler is complaining about, the code was working fine just moments ago, I added an extra method and everything broke. Removing the last changes did not fix it.

```
class NodeWrapper : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_ENUMS(NodeType NodeStatus)
    Q_PROPERTY(NodeType type READ type WRITE setType NOTIFY typeChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString typeString READ typeString NOTIFY typeChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(NodeStatus status READ status WRITE setStatus NOTIFY statusChanged)

public:
    NodeWrapper(QObject * parent = 0) : QObject(parent) { }

    enum NodeType {
        T_NODE,
        T_FOLDER
    };

    enum NodeStatus {
        S_OK,
        S_WARNING,
        S_ERROR
    };

    // type
    inline NodeType type() { return _type; }
    inline QString typeString() { return metaObject()->enumerator(0).key(type()); }
    inline void setType(NodeType v) {
        if (_type != v) {
            _type = v;
            emit typeChanged();
        }
    }
    // status
    inline NodeStatus status() { return _node.getStatus(); }
    inline void setStatus(NodeStatus v) {
        if (_node.getStatus() != v) {
            _node.setStatus(v);
            emit statusChanged();
        }
    }

signals:
    void typeChanged();
    void statusChanged();

private:
    NodeType _type;
    Node _node;
};
```

The errors begin at the `S_OK` member of the `NodeStatus` enum:

```
error: expected identifier before '(' token
         S_OK,
         ^
error: expected '}' before '(' token
error: expected ')' before numeric constant
         S_OK,
         ^
error: 'NodeType' does not name a type
     inline NodeType type() { return _type; }
            ^
error: 'metaObject' was not declared in this scope
     inline QString typeString() { return metaObject()->enumerator(0).key(type()); }
                                                     ^
error: 'type' was not declared in this scope
     inline QString typeString() { return metaObject()->enumerator(0).key(type()); }
                                                                               ^
...
```

Comment: "Removing the last changes did not fix it." Have you done a full rebuild?

Comment: Yes, including full clean and manual qmake run.

Comment: It looks like something evil has defined `S_OK` as a macro.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At a guess you've inadvertently included `<windows.h>` before this definition, which redefines S_OK as a number through #define and thus causing a compile error in the enumeration. This type of clutter in the global namespace is an unfortunate consequence of C compatibility, and in practice the safest bet is to just rename the field (S_SUCCESS perhaps?)

Comment: Inadvertently included what?

Comment: @user2341104 Some QT stuff maybe?

Answer (score 2):

S_OK is defined as an HRESULT of zero (winerror.h).
Try another prefix such as NS_OK or nsOK.

Comment: S_OK exists for over 20 years, it's the success return code for WIN32 API.

Answer (score 1):

If you google for `S_OK define`, you'll find that in some windows header it is defined as `(HRESULT)0x00000000` - which explains the compiler complaining about parens and numeric constants.

What you can do to get rid of that error:

- don't include WinAPI headers in places where you want to use that constant, or
- rename it to something else. Maybe lose the `S_` prefix or use another prefix.

The latter is more likely to work, as you will come across WinAPI headers often times. Maybe even QT exposes your classes to them, and as `S_OK` is an evil `#define`, you have little chance to fight it.